How does the Fluke I410 clamp meter compare to the similarly priced Fluke 324 clamp meter?
I'm comparing the Fluke I410, to the Fluke 324,

The Fluke I410 enables AC/DC amp measuring with an accessory clamp on the Fluke 87V. It handles 400 amp, ac and dc voltage to 600v. It's $250.
The Fluke 324 a dedicate clamp meter that can measure AC/DC amps and voltage. It handles 400 amp, ac and dc voltage to 600v. It's $250.

Am I missing something here? Why is the value in the I410?

The problem with this question is that it asks for opinions.  That is generally frowned upon here.  That said: I think it is a valid question.  I would suggest you start by reading (carefully) the data sheets for both models.  Then do a Google search for reviews on both units.  Maybe also try a Google search for both model numbers in the same search.

It's only an opinion if there is no objective merit in the response. That's not always the case. If I ask why people don't take a cruise ship from New York to San Francisco the answer is obviously because there is no reasonably direct waterway between the two that can accommodate it. It's technically an opinion, because you could build it first. But that's also insane.

But the objective in the response you could just get by reading the data sheets. Apart from that, which spec point one care the most about is either opinion-based or application-based (or both).

It's not what the meters offer, it's all about what you NEED. So make a list of what you need and work from there.

@SolarMike I don't agree, and your statement is philosophical. One meter has DC Amp measurements, the other doesn't. Regardless of whether or not I need that, if I want it I have to pay $100 more for it in a stand alone then I would with the i410: I originally though the comparison was between the Fluke 324 and i410, and the proper comparison would have been between the Fluke 325 and i410.

A few points of comparison:

The I410 measures DC amps, the other does not.  That's a huge advantage in some cases. How else are you going to easily measure the current drawn by a 12V starter motor, for example? However, it requires another 9V battery to work, and the zero has to be manually nulled (and it will drift around). That's a side effect of the (Hall) technology used to measure DC with a clamp-on. It's also only CAT III 600V rated.

The 324 is CAT III 600V and CAT IV 300V rated. The difference is not great, but will open up a few other kinds of measurements for which the other would not be deemed safe. It measures only AC so no zero adjustment is necessary.
It has a useful thermocouple temperature measurement feature of good accuracy and a capacitance function that is suitable for checking motor run and start capacitors, and a resistance function suitable for checking mains-powered heaters and such like.

The 87V is CAT III 1000V, CAT IV 600V so it's suitable for a wide range of voltage measurements including many industrial 3-phase service entrances. Either of your options is not safe in as many situations.


Both have min/max feature so you can measure peak current draw (but for AC-only with the 324- so if you need to measure peak current draw of a DC motor you're out of luck).
I didn't compare the accuracy and current ranges- they are broadly similar, and we don't know what you need. Usually really accurate measurements are not required when you are using a clamp-on.
You are really making a false comparison, a better one would be the 325 vs. the I410 since both then would have DC current measurement capability. Or the 324 vs. the i400. The latter requires no batteries.

I agree fully, this was a bad question lol. I didn't see that that the 324 didn't do DC AMP. Easily answered though, and light of that it's obvious: when we take into account the 325 is comparable to the i410, but it's $100 more. Tada, everything is within the margins of "making sense" again. Anyway, I'm going to update this question to i400 vs 324 to be specific, seems like the question is still valuable to be people evaluating between the two.

I410: AC & DC amps, only measures current.
324: AC amps only, has voltage, temp, capacitance functionality that is suitable for electricians (not suitable for a general electronics lab).
The DC measurement feature (most likely a Hall effect sensor) costs extra and is a marketing thing.

How is DC measurement feature "a marketing thing"? I have the I410, but have only ever used it on DC.

@MrGerber Pricing is a marketing thing.  OP was wondering why both devices were at the same price point when the 324 has more features except for DC current measuring ability.

Sure, price is marketing, but "the DC measurement feature [...] is a marketing thing" doesn't refer to the price but the feature. That's why I was asking.
